# Moving box2d bodies randomly in entire screen

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I want to fly b2bodies with in the entire screen randomly. Now I'm using ccMoveTo but it does not look soo good. Can anyone tell me if there is any easy method to move without using ccMoveTo or ccBazierTo?

The example game  http://www.agame.com/game/chickaboom.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

body->setlinearvelocity(b2vec2(randomNumber1, randomNumber2));